# Difference between db.collectionX.save and db.collectionX.insert

Tags: mongodb

```
> itemsA = { attrA : "vA", attrB : "vB" }
{ "attrA" : "vA", "attrB" : "vB" }
> db.collectionA.insert(itemsA)
> db.collectionA.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e85de174808245ad59cc83f"), "attrA" : "vA", "attrB" : "vB" }
> itemsA
{ "attrA" : "vA", "attrB" : "vB" }


> itemsB = { attrC : "vC", attrD : "vD" }
{ "attrC" : "vC", "attrD" : "vD" }
> db.collectionB.save(itemsB)
> db.collectionB.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e85de474808245ad59cc840"), "attrC" : "vC", "attrD" : "vD" }
> itemsB
{
    "attrC" : "vC",
    "attrD" : "vD",
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e85de474808245ad59cc840")
}
```

Here is my observation:

After being inserted into **collectionA**, the value of **itemsA** is not modified.

In the contrast, after being stored into **collectionB**, the value of **itemB** is changed!

Is there any rule that guides those modifications so that I know what should be expected after a value is either inserted or saved into a collection?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between save and insert in Mongo DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209681/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-insert-in-mongo-db)

Answer (score 3):

For save, if you provide _id, it will update. If you don't, it will insert. One neat feature about Mongo's JavaScript shell is if you call a function without the executing parentesis, it will return the implementation.  This is useful if you are curious about any of MongoDB's methods and don't feel like sorting through all of the source code!

In the JS shell:

```
> db.test.save
function (obj) {
    if (obj == null || typeof obj == "undefined") {
        throw "can't save a null";
    }
    if (typeof obj == "number" || typeof obj == "string") {
        throw "can't save a number or string";
    }
    if (typeof obj._id == "undefined") {
        obj._id = new ObjectId;
        return this.insert(obj);
    } else {
        return this.update({_id:obj._id}, obj, true);
    }
}
> db.test.insert
function (obj, _allow_dot) {
    if (!obj) {
        throw "no object passed to insert!";
    }
    if (!_allow_dot) {
        this._validateForStorage(obj);
    }
    if (typeof obj._id == "undefined") {
        var tmp = obj;
        obj = {_id:new ObjectId};
        for (var key in tmp) {
            obj[key] = tmp[key];
        }
    }
    this._mongo.insert(this._fullName, obj);
    this._lastID = obj._id;
}
```

From this, we can see that save is a wrapper for update and insert.

Functionally, save and insert are very similar, especially if no _id value is passed.  However, if an _id key is passed, save() will update the document, while insert() will throw a duplicate key error.

Answer (score 2):

For save, if you provide _id, it will update. If you don't, it will insert, that's the differences.