# mongodb-while insert a new document in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

i'm new to mongodb,while using connection of mongodb with java both insert and put methods are used to insert a document in a collection of mongodb. So what is the difference in using insert and put option

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between save and insert in Mongo DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209681/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-insert-in-mongo-db)

Comment: both are used for inserting purpose

Comment: please show your code, I don't understand on wich object you use put().