# How to append form fields using angular and how to insert value in DB

Tags: angularjs, arrays, node.js, insert

I am using express and mongoose to save data in mongodb.
I am creating Node API, Below is my Mongo Schema.

```
var bookSchema=new Schema({ 
    subject_name:{type:String}, 
    books:[{book_name:String, book_author:String}] 
});
```

My html view is as below

[image]

I want to append books more than one in respect to a single subject name. So I want to know that How can I append Books section more than once using Angularjs and how to store its value in mongodb.

and I expect the result something like that:

[image]

Please Let me how can I do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: may be this video will help you [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZm85UZQLd2RyFN1IQWuOk8gBt0aJHE1F)

Comment: Thanks for the video link @ThanhTùng I know how to insert data in db but I want to know that when I append boook section more than once then `ng-model` of appended elements will be more than once , so I need to create its array to submit it in db... so I want to know how I can insert appended data in DB

Comment: @SaurabhSharma you need help in nodejs code or angular code? Are you able to send the required data from UI to node backend server?

Comment: Basically I need help in Nodejs.... I am able to insert data in DB when I have only one book.... If I have  multiple books then I need help to insert data.

Comment: `book_name` and `book_author` html elements will append on click `Add More Books` button

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you check if this helps `SubjectBooks` is mongoose schema. The query for appending new books into the subject by subjectName. You can change first parameter of update method if you want to find objects with any other parameter like _id.

Node code goes here

**EDITED**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/*....mongoose connection creation code goes here...*/

var bookSchema=new Schema({subject_name:{type:String},books[{book_name:String, book_author:String}]
});
var SubjectBooks = mongoose.model('<collection_name>', bookSchema);

app.post('<URL mapping goes here>',function(req,res){
    var subject = req.body; //You have to use body-parser
    var subjectName = subject.subject_name;
    var subjectModel = new SubjectBooks(subject);
    subjectModel.save(function (err,mongRes) {
       if(err){
           res.send(err);
       }
       res.json(mongRes);
    });
});
```

Angular code that I have created

```
app.controller("mainController",["$scope",'mainService',function($scope,mainService){
$scope.subjectBookCatalogue = {
    subject_name: "",
    books:[{
        book_name:"",
        book_author:""
    }]
};

$scope.saveSubjects = function (data) {
    mainService.saveSubjects(data).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    },function(response){
    });
};

$scope.subjects = [];
$scope.fetchSubjects = function () {
    mainService.getAllSubjects().then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.subjects = response.data;
    },function(response){
    });
};


$scope.fetchSubjects();

$scope.submitForm = function(){
    console.log($scope.subjectBookCatalogue);
    $scope.saveSubjects($scope.subjectBookCatalogue);
}
}]);

app.factory("mainService",["$http",function($http){
return {
    saveSubjects : function(data){
        return $http({
            method:"POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/subject/"+data.subject_name,
            data:data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    },
    getAllSubjects : function(){
        return $http({
                        method:"GET",
                        url:"http://localhost:3000/v1/subjects"
                     });
    }
}
}]);
```

This should help for pushing books into a subject books array.

You can refer this question

- [What is the difference between save and insert in Mongo DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209681/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-insert-in-mongo-db)

Comment: hey, I don't want to update document. I want when I post newly fresh record  in DB then do the same as `update`

Comment: What you need is `{upsert:true}` flag within update query. What this does is it insert new document if no document is found in the db.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I have updated my solution can you verify if this is what you need. Now it is inserting if new subject data comes in.

Comment: One thing that I was missing was $each modifier due to which array of books was getting pushed into another object containing multiple books object.

Comment: Hi, I go through your above given code and analyse that  is for Update the existing document. But I don't have existing document. I am inserting and using `post` method. Or might be I am not getting which you  trying to say.

Comment: From front end I am getting 
`{ 
    "subject_name" : "Maths",
    "books" : [ 
        {
            "book_name" : "Publications",
            "book_author" : "A.R Rehman" 
        }, 
        {
            "book_name" : "PS Publications",
            "book_author" : "Rohit Karla" 
        }
        , 
        {
            "book_name" : "PLA",
            "book_author" : "Mukesh Rathi" 
        }
    ] 
}` So, Now I want to insert that JSON in a single request.

Comment: As per my need your logic is not working. I want to insert my data with below given schema
 
`var SubSchema=new subjectSchema({
  subject_name:req.body.subject_name,
  books:[
  {
   book_name:req.body.book_name, 
   book_author:req.body.book_author
  },
  {
   book_name:req.body.book_name, 
   book_author:req.body.book_author
  },
  ... and so on.
  ]
 });
 SubSchema.save(function(err,data){
  if(err){res.json(err)}
   else{
    res.json(data)
   }
 })`

Comment: Save will insert new document. why you are creating new schema every time just use operations on parent schema itself

Comment: As in PHP , If we want to insert multiple value from same name attribute, so we make the `name="something[]"` like that and after serialize that generated array and then insert in to db. Same thing I want to do with Node.js...Please let me know if get some idea.

Comment: Hey @SaurabhSharma I have added mongoose model in the reply I guess what I am missing was `SubjectBooks` declaration.  I have added those lines. Please check if now it helps

Comment: Hi, I solved this issue what I need. By angular I am send data to api like 
` $scope.dd={books:[{ "book_name":"", "book_author":"" }] };
$scope.addmore=function(){  $scope.dd.books.push({});  }
$scope.cccc=function(){ $http.post('/multi', $scope.dd).success(function(res){ console.log(res); }) }`

Comment: and in Node API 
`router.post('/multi',function(req,res){   
 var SubSchema=new subjectSchema({ subject_name:req.body.subject_name, books:req.body.books });
 SubSchema.save(function(err,data){
  if(err){res.json(err)}
   else{ res.json(data) } }) })`
Now I storing data as per my expectation and Schema Model

Comment: Ok great. But lets say I make another request with same subject name and add only one book in the request is it appending in mongo or just saving one entry after overriding all books array with just 1 entry even if earlier there were lets say 3 books for that subject?

Comment: whatever you said its a condition of updation of  existing document. But in my case I was not updating document instead I was inserting fresher document. Suppose I am saving a subject name and that subject contains more than one books, Thats why subject name was one but books name & author can be add more on demand.

Comment: That case can be handled just by using save command in my suggestion too.