# Best way to update data in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb

Mongoose is the ORM for mongodb which simplify mongodb query.
So using some of mongoose function as alternative to mongodb function seems preferable. But in the case of updating data in mongodb there is diffrent ways.
Please which is more prferable for large data in these list of options.

1. save() // mongoose save data also update data and nested data
2. update() // I dont understand the diffrent between this and save().
3. findOneAndUpdate();

Which is the best pratice.

Answer (score 0):

For the difference between `save()` and `update()`, I invite you to read the response of Rahul in this topic : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209681/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-insert-in-mongo-db)

**Between `update()` and `findOneAndUpdate()` :**

the `update()` method can modify one or multiple documents (with the option `multi`) while `findOneAndUpdate()` will modify only one document. An other difference is that `findOneAndUpdate()` require a write lock during the operation and do atomic operation.

So the best approach depend of your need in your application. For my part, I use `update()` most of time.