# How can I save a record to mongoDB by skipping a field which is marked as required in the Mongoose schema in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I have a schema in which a field is marked as required,I have many records to insert to db but one record will not have the field which is marked as required, but I would like to insert that record also without entering data to the filed that is marked as required.  Is there any posiibilty that I can do insertion to db  in  such a way. How can I manage that record from giving the error field required.

fi

```
e
ld2: {
          type: String,
          required: function() {
            if(this.field2) { return true }
            else return false
          }
        }
        //trying to insert the data from controller
        //some code..
        let jsonData ={field2 :"",field2 :'abcd'}
        var test = new SchemaTest()//creating schema instance
        for(var i in jsonData)
        //for below code for first iteration field2  have no data, 
        //second have data
        test.field2 = jsonData.field2 
        test.save((err,test)=> {})
```

Comment: Which DB are you talking about?

Comment: I am trying to save to mongodb

Comment: How about using [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/)? It skips validation.

Comment: Is it possible to insert a schema instance to DB usng the 'insert', does the save and insert plays the same role, except insert skips validation?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209681/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-insert-in-mongo-db) for difference

Answer (score 0):

The probable thing to do would be to remove the required field. If not all records will have the field filled then it should not be set as required.
You can otherwise use an if statement to set it to true if some other property turns to be true.

```js
//Other code.
field1 :{
  type: Boolean,
  required: true
},
field2: {
  type: String,
  required: function() {
    if(this.field1) { return true }
    else return false
  }
}
// Rest of code
```

Comment: I have made some changes to my code by using your solution, could you please check if its correct?

Comment: Do you have a link?